# aligning a line of text left in a paragraph? CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a line of text like so:

```
I am john doe blah blah blah.
```

How can I align it like so:

```
I am john doe
blah blah blah
```

Comment: Did you try `text-align: left` and `display: block` with fixed width?

Comment: By restricting the width using `max-width`? Not sure what you mean. Also, your "aligned" example has more "blah"s than your line of text.

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: So it does, failure.

Comment: I did try the text-align: left, but I can not get it to paragraph as I showed.

Comment: If you are going to down vote, give a reason or doing so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways:

1. Set the width of the text container so that the desired line break
   occurs
2. Use `<br>` where you want the line break
3. Wrap each 'line' of text in a `<span>`, and style them with CSS for the desired effect.

The 'right' way really depends on context. Perhaps you could say more about that.

Comment: Maybe ask before post an answer?

Comment: the   <br> and    <span worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: @LGSon - Yeah I suppose. Sometimes I like to walk around with a shotgun. :/

Comment: Sometimes a technical correct answer is far from the best, hence really good to ask for the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the line break element `<br>`.

**Example:**

`My name is Adam and i live in<br>South Africa.`

will display as:

```
My name is Adam and i live in<br> South Africa
```